# Refresh angular component when related data is saved from another angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack, angular-components

I am working on MEAN stack and Angular, and have this method below in one angular component named **itemListDetailsComponent** (in .ts file):

```
onStatusUpdateClick() {

    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
        console.log('queryParams', params['itemId']);
        this.itemsUpdateService.updateItemStatus(
          params['itemId'],
          this.activatedRoute.data).subscribe(data => {
            this.itemsUpdateService.statusChanged.emit("Status Changed");
        }, error => {super.handleError(error, (err) => {console.log(err)})});            
    });

}
```

Also, there is another angular component (**itemsSideListComponent**) which displays a list of all items with their status.
Now, once the **itemsListDetailComponent** saves and updates the status of the selected item, I need to *refresh* the displayed list of items in the **itemsSideListComponent**.

Any info, how can I refresh the **itemsSideListComponent** for the list of *visible items*, as soon as the data of a selected item from the **itemListDetailsComponent** is saved/updated.

Please help as I am completely new to angular.

Comment: Can the down voters please comment why its down voted.. ?

Comment: Check the property ?`@Output()` of components. Use it after a selected item from the itemListDetailsComponent is saved/updated.

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID , can u pls elaborate more abt Output keyword - should I put it as an attribute on the save method or on the component class for the 'itemListDetailsComponent' ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `itemListDetailsComponent` must declare an output event that is fired when an item is saved/updated.

```
export class itemListDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onSaveOrUpdate = new EventEmitter<Item>();

  onSave(item: any) {
    // save and emit an event.
    this.onSaveOrUpdate.emit(item);
  }

  onUpdate(item: any) {
    // update and emit an event.
    this.onSaveOrUpdate.emit(item);
  }
}
```

My answer is based on an assymption that the parent component (The component in which `itemListDetailsComponent` and `itemsSideListComponent` exists) is 'orchestring' the data and that your two component are juste responsible for displaying it.

**ParentComponent.html**

```
<item-list-detail (onSaveOrUpdate)="doRefreshList($event)"></item-list-detail>
<item-side-list [listToDisplay]="list"></item-side-list>
```

This implies that `itemsSideListComponent` take as an Input the data to display. So :

```
export class itemListDetailsComponent {

    @Input()
    listToDisplay: any[];

}
```

**ParentComponent.ts**

```
list: Item[]

doRefreshList(item: any) {

// Make a server call or add item to list...
this.list.push(item);
}
```

*You may need to make a change detection according to whether your list is immutable or not.*

Comment: shouldnt the @Input() be on itemsSideListComponent list variable. Also, I m calling OnSaveOrUpdate() method inside itemListDetailsComponent.html and the listToDisplay binding is inside itemsSideListComponent.html; and not on ParentComponent.html. No method is called from ParentComponent.html. Will it be possible for you to update the answer?

Comment: It depends on how you page is structured. You only have two components  and itemsSideListComponent is inside itemListDetailsComponent ? PLease give us you html code

Answer (score -1):

You can use event emitter service.

Here is the documentation https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

When you are done with the work in 1 component emit an event with some specific id. And listen (subscribe) that event to your desired component. There you can also pass data to that listening component.